# Multiple .properties files in a Java project

Tags: java, deployment, configuration, properties

I would like to find an expedient way to switch between multiple `.properties` files for different deployment configurations.

My initial inclination is to create a separate file, `selector.properties`, whose single property is used to determine the proper file:

`properties.file=deploymentConfiguration1.properties`

...for one deployment, or:

`properties.file=deploymentConfiguration2.properties`

...for the next deployment.

Another developer on my team has an `ApplicationProperties` class wherein:

`private static final String PROP_FILE="someFileName.properties";`

...is the means to do this.  However, I want to switch properties files **without** rebuilding!  Thanks in advance for your input.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should have been more clear initially, but this is for a set of web services packaged as an AAR. I will just drop it into the web server and let Tomcat and Axis2 do their thing.

So, I don't think some of the answers with command-line params will work in this context.

Comment: Are you using any framework or toolkit in your project which can aid in doing this (e.g., spring)?

Comment: We're using JSF and Weld in the web application portion of our project.

Comment: It seems to me that you found the solution to your problem. What's the problem with this solution?

Comment: Oh, I just want something slicker if possible `=)`

Comment: Just a note, please specify your question before posting it and if you need to change it totally (like this one) - create a new question instead!

Comment: Sorry!  It was clear to me when I asked it, but (obviously) was not objectively clear.  I'll post another; thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have multiple property files, one per env, eg;

```
application-dev.properties
application-test.properties
application-prod.properties
```

Launch your app with the env as a system property;

```
java -Denv=test
```

Load your properties from the relevant file;

```
String props = "application-" + System.getProperty("env") + ".properties";
```

Note that I'd generally discourage this in favour of a properties file with a fixed name where the file is generated at *build* time.

**Edit:**
If it's a web app, you can set the value of env in the deployment descriptor (web.xml)

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>myEnv</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>test</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

then you can get the value in your web app like this;

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
String env = (String)envCtx.lookup("myEnv");
String props = "application-" + env + ".properties";
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Maybe I should have been more clear in the question, but this is for a set of web services packaged as an AAR.  I will just drop it into a Tomcat server.  Is there a similar way to do what you suggest if I'm not running the project directly?

Answer (score 2):

Add a argument that points out the configuration file!

```
java Program -config deploymentConfiguration2.properties
```

Comment: I agree. A command-line argument or command-line system property is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using a "property manager" property file sounds good.
The master property file could be passed as a parameter to the vm via a jvm argument
But one downside of this process is that the master property file becomes unmanaged over a period of time. For example you may end up retaining some old property file references which no longer makes sense.