# Multiple properties files

Tags: java, properties

In a java application, I am using .properties file to access application related config properties.
For eg.
`AppConfig.properties` the contents of which are say,

```
settings.user1.name=userone
settings.user2.name=usertwo
settings.user1.password=Passwrd1!
settings.user2.password=Passwrd2!
```

I am accesing these properties through a java file - `AppConfiguration.java` like

```
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();
    public AppConfiguration(){
        properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig.properties"));
}
```

Now, instead of keeping all the key-value properties in one file, I would like to divide them in few files(AppConfig1.properties, AppConfig2.properties, AppConfig3.properties etc.).
I would like to know if it is possible to load these multiple files simultaneously.

My question is not similar to - [Multiple .properties files in a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864804/multiple-properties-files-in-a-java-project)

Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Simply have multiple load statements.

```
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig1.properties"));
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig2.properties"));
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig2.properties"));
```

All the key-value pairs will be available to use using the properties object.

Comment: Wow, that simple. I should have thought that. Thank you very much. I might go with this or the solution by @duffymo

Comment: If "my.property" is present in AppConfig1 as well as in AppConfig2, will the properties object contain the value from the first or the second file ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have two objectives in mind:

1. Partition one very large .properties file into several smaller ones where the (key, value) pairs are related.
2. Ensure that all .properties files are available at the same time, even if you read them simultaneously using threads.

If that's the case, I'd proceed with partitioning the .properties into several files and write a new class that handles the reading of individual .properties files and the merging of all the results into a single Properties instance.

Answer (score 0):

As [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) objects are in fact map, you can use all of their methods, including `putAll(...)`. In your case, it would be useful to load each Property file using a separate Properties object, then merge them in your application properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for you:

- You can have different properties object for different properties files
- You can merge them using `putAll()`.

  `Properties properties1 = new Properties();
  properties1.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig1.properties"));
  Properties properties2 = new Properties();
  properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream("AppConfig2.properties"));
  Properties merged = new Properties();
  merged.putAll(properties1);
  merged.putAll(properties2);`