# How to load and read the multiple property files using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 property files like `web1.properties`, `web2.properties`, `web3.properties`. I would like to load all the property files at a time using single property object.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load("web1.properties");
prop.load("web2.properties");
prop.load("web3.properties");`
```

I'm Trying the below code for load multiple property files.

```
public class ReadFileExtension {
    static Properties prop = new Properties();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String projectFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File f1 = new File(projectFolder);
        File[] listOfFiles = f1.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Length:"+listOfFiles.length);
        for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++){
            if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                //System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                String prop1 = listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                if(prop1.contains("properties")){
                    System.out.println(prop1);

                    File folder = new File(prop1);
                    File[] listOfFiles1 = folder.listFiles();

                        for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles1.length; j++) {
                          if (listOfFiles1[j].isFile()) {
                            //System.out.println("Feature File: " + listOfFiles1[j].getAbsolutePath());
                            //prop.load(new FileInputStream(listOfFiles1[j].getAbsolutePath()));
                            prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(listOfFiles1[j].getAbsolutePath()));
                          } 
                        }
                }
              } 
        }
        System.out.println("Prop 1: "+prop.getProperty("ApplicationURL"));
        System.out.println("Prop 2: "+prop.getProperty("Application"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093432/multiple-properties-files).

Comment: what did you get if you execute the code you posted ?

Comment: @Abhishek NullPointerException when run the code in that link.

Comment: @user3145373ツ When load more than one properties like this. It will take the last property file

Answer (score 1):

You Can load mutiple properties using this syntax.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.load(new FileInputStream("web1.properties"));

Properties properties2 = new Properties();
properties2.load(new FileInputStream("web2.properties"));

properties.putAll(properties2);
```

Reading properties would be same.

Comment: This one is for two property files. I need to load three properties like this.

Comment: Just add code to read third file and the properties to first object

Answer (score 1):

I think the link Abhishek provided you will work.

I have tested it on my local machine and works fine for me.

Code:

```
public class MultiplePropertyLoader {

    private static Properties properties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/SecurityKey.properties"));
            properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/SecurityKey1.properties"));
            properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/SecurityKey2.properties"));

            System.out.println("::: Property File 1 Data :::");
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("ENCRYPTION_KEY"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("USERNAME"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("PASSWORD"));

            System.out.println("::: Property File 2 Data :::");
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("ENCRYPTION_KEY1"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("USERNAME1"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("PASSWORD1"));

            System.out.println("::: Property File 3 Data :::");
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("ENCRYPTION_KEY2"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("USERNAME2"));
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("PASSWORD2"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please post me if that does not work.

Here's a [my git repository URL](https://github.com/kurbhatt/BestPractices/blob/master/src/org/property_loader/MultiplePropertyLoader.java) with running code and sample data.
You can clone repository and run in your local machine, it will work.

Comment: Hello @tsivarajan if this answer fixed your issue then please accept the answer.